# VBA [EXCEL 2013]: Automation: Open Links in Same Browser Window / Tab

Tags: excel, vba, parsing, web-scraping, internet-explorer-11

I want to parse with VBA (Excel) a long list of local webpages (`.HTM` files) and extract some data into excel. There are more than 9000 webpages which the program needs to scrape. This is an example:

```
> C:\Users\User_ID\Webpages\BS_1000.HTM.htm
C:\Users\User_ID\Webpages\BS_1001.HTM.htm
C:\Users\User_ID\Webpages\BS_1002.HTM.htm
C:\Users\User_ID\Webpages\BS_1003.HTM.htm
C:\Users\User_ID\Webpages\BS_1006.HTM.htm
C:\Users\User_ID\Webpages\BS_1007.HTM.htm
C:\Users\User_ID\Webpages\BS_1011.HTM.htm
C:\Users\User_ID\Webpages\BS_1012.HTM.htm
C:\Users\User_ID\Webpages\BS_1015.HTM.htm
C:\Users\User_ID\Webpages\BS_1016.HTM.htm
[... and the list goes on ...]
```

Here is the VBA:

```
<!-- language: lang-HTML -->
For startNumber = 1 To TotalProfiles
Dim ie As InternetExplorerMedium
Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium
ie.Visible = True

Application.StatusBar = "Loading profile " & ProfileNumber & " from a total of " & TotalProfiles & " profiles"
Set currentProfile = Worksheets("List_of_Files").Range("B" & CurrentRowPosition)
ie.navigate currentProfile

Application.StatusBar = "Loading profile: " & ProfileNumber & "; file location: " & currentProfile
Do While ie.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE_COMPLET
DoEvents
Loop

Application.StatusBar = "Storing " & currentProfile & " information into HTMLElement"
Set html = ie.document
Set ie = Nothing
[some code here...]
```

The problem is that my current code opens each page in a new IE window (without closing the previous). With more than 9000 webpages to scrape, this can very soon be a very big problem.

I use Internet Explorer 11 (on Windows 7 Enterprise SP1) with Microsoft Office 2013.

What I would like is that IE should open each webpage in the same tab (pretty much just refresh the already "in use" tab after finishing parsing and load the next page - or at least close the window after finishing parsing and open the next webpage in a "new" window). Sadly, I didn't manage to find a solution until now. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it opens a new window each time is that you tell it to at the beginning of your loop with this line `Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium`

There are two ways to solve it.

1. Initiate IE before the loop, then quit IE after the loop is done:

Like so:

```
Dim ie As InternetExplorerMedium
Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium
ie.Visible = True

For startNumber = 1 To TotalProfiles

     Application.StatusBar = "Loading profile: " & ProfileNumber & "; file location: " & currentProfile
     Do While ie.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE_COMPLET
          DoEvents
     Loop

     Set currentProfile = Worksheets("List_of_Files").Range("B" & CurrentRowPosition)
     ie.navigate currentProfile

     Application.StatusBar = "Storing " & currentProfile & " information into HTMLElement"

     Set html = ie.document

     [some code here...]

Next

Set html = Nothing
ie.Quit
Set ie = Nothing
```

2. Quit the IE instance each time before you end your loop (probably not as efficient as first way)

Like so:

```
For startNumber = 1 To TotalProfiles

     Dim ie As InternetExplorerMedium
     Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium
     ie.Visible = True

     Application.StatusBar = "Loading profile " & ProfileNumber & " from a total of " & TotalProfiles & " profiles"
     Set currentProfile = Worksheets("List_of_Files").Range("B" & CurrentRowPosition)
     ie.navigate currentProfile

     Application.StatusBar = "Loading profile: " & ProfileNumber & "; file location: " & currentProfile
     Do While ie.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE_COMPLET
          DoEvents
     Loop

     Application.StatusBar = "Storing " & currentProfile & " information into HTMLElement"
     Set html = ie.document

     [some code here...]

     Set html = Nothing
     ie.Quit
     Set ie = Nothing

Next
```

Comment: @user3185735 - second pair of eyes always helps :)