# Excel VBA fails to load Internet Explorer

Tags: vba, excel, parsing, internet-explorer

I have a list of local webpages (over 9000) which I want to parse with Excel VBA.
I use Office 2013 with IE 11 on:

- a Windows 7 Enterprise Pro x64, 16 GB RAM, i7 - Processor but also on
- a Windows 8.1 Enterprise x64, 12 GB RAM, i7 - Processor

The problem on both machiens is that after successfuly parsing about 70-80 pages, the programm suddenly fails to load the next webpage into IE. It gets "stuck" so to say (see comment in the code below). If I reset the programm, then it can parse without problen again about 70-80 profiles after "failing" again.

**[EDIT: I'm sorry, I posted by mistake the wrong code. Here is the corrected
   version]**

Here is a part of the code:

```
    <!-- language: lang-HTML -->
Sub ImportFromWebpage()

    'GLOBAL VARIABLES
    Dim html As HTMLDocument
    Dim CurrentRowPosition, ProfileNumber, TotalProfiles As Integer
    Dim TempProfileID As String
    Dim profileRange, posCounter, currentProfile As Range
        Set profileRange = Worksheets("List_of_Files").Range("B2:B20000")
        ProfileNumber = 519
        CurrentRowPosition = 520
        TotalProfiles = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(profileRange)
    'MsgBox "TotalProfiles = " & TotalProfiles



    'VARIABLES NEEDED FOR PARSING HERE
    'ELEMENTS
    Dim firstIHTMLElmt, secondIHTMLElmt, thirdIHTMLElmt As IHTMLElement
    Dim firstTempIHTMLElmt, secondTempIHTMLElmt, thirdTempIHTMLElmt, fourthTempIHTMLElmt, fiftTempIHTMLElmt As IHTMLElement
    'COLLECTIONS
    Dim firstIHTMLEColl, secondIHTMLEColl, thirdIHTMLEColl As IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim firstTempIHTMLEColl, secondTempIHTMLEColl, thirdTempIHTMLEColl, fourthTempIHTMLEColl, fifthTempIHTMLEColl As IHTMLElementCollection

    Dim ie As InternetExplorerMedium
    Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium
    ie.Visible = False

    'FROM HERE LOOPING
    For startNumber = 1 To TotalProfiles

        Application.StatusBar = "Loading profile " & ProfileNumber & " from a total of " & TotalProfiles & " profiles"
        'Set currentProfile = Worksheets("List_of_Files").Range("J" & CurrentRowPosition) // OLD
        Set currentProfile = Worksheets("List_of_Files").Range("B" & CurrentRowPosition)
        ie.navigate currentProfile

        Application.StatusBar = "Loading profile: " & ProfileNumber & "; file location: " & currentProfile
            Do While ie.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
                DoEvents
            Loop

        Application.StatusBar = "Storing " & currentProfile & " information into HTMLElement"
        Set html = ie.document
        Set ie = Nothing

    [code, code, code, code ...]



    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

    Next startNumber

    Set html = Nothing
    ie.Quit
    Set ie = Nothing

    MsgBox "Done parsing all profiles!"

End Sub
```

Here is a screenshot from the Windows 8.1 task manager **AFTER failing to load**:
[image]

[image]

Dose someone have any clue about why this is happening? Not only on one machiene, but on both.

I an not very experience with programming and even less with VBA so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: when I [answered your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34169217/vba-excel-2013-automation-open-links-in-same-browser-window-tab/34169561#34169561) the other day, my first suggestion was to initiate IE *once* before looping, then navigate to each page using the same browser inside your loop. Why not try that? I suspect that the browser is not always quitting (by seeing how many are still open) and may be leading to your problem. Once you are done all your processing, you can then quit IE.

Comment: First thing, is that you create an instance of IE for every page in your list so your computer will be overloaded. Move that line `Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium` out of the loop and wait for the first page to be parsed to navigate to the new one and it should be better! ;)

Comment: Try to use **`Error Handling Blocks`** And **`On Error Goto`** in your code. At least it will help you to overcome creation of multiple instances of IE.

Comment: If you are going to create a new instance of IE for each page, you need to .Quit before you set IE = nothing.  However, much better to just re-use the same instance.

Comment: Scott, thank you for correcting me. I did change the code yesterday and it worked flawless. I accidentaly posted an outdated code. I changed it in the initial post. Thanky you once again. But still with this corrected code I get the above mentioned problem.

Comment: The updated code can't be correct because of the `Set ie = Nothing` line within the loop. The loop would only work once with this code in place. The only `Set ie = Nothing` line should be just after `ie.Quit` at the end of the macro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution proved to be a good one in my case. Don't know whether this is the best solution but it work very good for me.

- put `IE declaration` before the loop to initiate an instance of Internet Explorer; this is the only instance which will be used (the link is just going to be refreshed within this instance)
- `set html = Nothing` within the loop
- `set ie = Nothing` outside of the loop, so that only the link may be refreshed without restarting IE
- `ie.Quit` only after parsing all >9000 webpages (so outside of the loop)

Hope it helps others with the same problem.

```
Sub ImportFromWebpage()
'GLOBAL VARIABLES
Dim html As HTMLDocument
Dim CurrentRowPosition, ProfileNumber, TotalProfiles As Integer
Dim TempProfileID As String
Dim profileRange, posCounter, currentProfile As Range
    Set profileRange = Worksheets("List_of_Files").Range("B2:B20000")
    ProfileNumber = 1
    CurrentRowPosition = 2
    TotalProfiles = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(profileRange)
'MsgBox "TotalProfiles = " & TotalProfiles

Dim ie As InternetExplorerMedium
Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium
ie.Visible = False

'FROM HERE LOOPING
For startNumber = 1 To TotalProfiles

    Application.StatusBar = "Loading profile " & ProfileNumber & " from a total of " & TotalProfiles & " profiles"
    'Set currentProfile = Worksheets("List_of_Files").Range("J" & CurrentRowPosition) // OLD
    Set currentProfile = Worksheets("List_of_Files").Range("B" & CurrentRowPosition)
    ie.navigate currentProfile

    Application.StatusBar = "Loading profile: " & ProfileNumber & "; file location: " & currentProfile
        Do While ie.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            DoEvents
        Loop

    Application.StatusBar = "Storing " & currentProfile & " information into HTMLElement"
    Set html = ie.document

    [code, code, code, code ...]

    Set html = Nothing
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

Next startNumber

  Set ie = Nothing
  ie.Quit
  MsgBox "Done parsing all profiles!"
End Sub
```